# How can I get text from Google Assistant so that I can parse the text to do certain action?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to build an Android app that inside the app when user long press the home button, Google Assistant will pop up (which is current system behavior), then my app can get the text that user has said which appears in GA. I know that GA provide system actions support, but the action I need to implement is not in system actions. Is there any example or material for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't control what happens when the user opens the Google Assistant, even if they've opened it while your Android app is active. You can only be passed input by the Google Assistant if the user invokes your action by requesting it after they open the Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, instead of using Google Assistant I actually used Google Speech-To-Text to solved the problem.